# MVC partial view searching order?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I got confused with MVC partial view's searching order.

For example, my site url from d:\mysite is:
http://localhost:8039/Admin/Contents/Create/FundswireArticle

There is no physical folder called d:\mysite\Admin or d:\mysite\Admin\Contents (they are controlled by routing to some other places).

From file monitor, I actually see that my app was trying to find 
d:\mysite\Admin and d:\mysite\Admin, it can't find it (as it wasn't there), then it goes to use routing.

Is this a normal behavior for MVC (I am running under .net 4.5)?

Comment: Your question was not clear, can you elaborate more?

Comment: What part is not clear? Say I visit http://localhost:8039/Admin/Contents/Create/FundswireArticle. I don't have a physical folder called Admin, instead the routing table will route the traffic to /Jerry/Test. From sysinternal file monitor, I can see that IIS first try to find Admin folder and Admin/Create Folder on my local harddrive. Then it will go to routing table to go to the real places.

Comment: Where exactly your site content is present? What is your Route config? Did you created any Virtual directories?

Comment: There is no virtual directory. The route config is just normal mvc route. End of the day MVC found the partial view, but looks like it first goes to Admin/Contents other than what I set up in the routing table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is the normal behavior of MVC now. I simplified the test code to:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Test",
            url: "{Test}/{Index}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The url to access is: http://localhost:6666/Test/Index
You can see that the routing will route the traffic to Home Controller.

From file monitor, I saw these:

Request File d:\testspeed\Test

Request File d:\testspeed\Test\Web.config

Request File d:\testspeed\Test\Index

Request File d:\testspeed\Test\Index\Web.config

All requests failed as there is no test folder. 
Then it goes to read all the dlls in bin folder, web donfigs and then loads
Home folder and all javascripts.

This demos that in deed MVC will search for a physical folder with same name mentioned in url.